# Response of Python Google App Engine application is auto cached

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching

I uploaded an application to Google App Engine, which will connect to the REST service of another web site, say mydomain.com.

In the first 2 requests, the responses are correct. However, since 3rd request, the response is always the same as the 2nd request. Even there are some changes in the REST result of mydomain.com.

I have checked the log and found that my Python module does not seem to be revoked. The response is from sort of cache. I have checked some materials. Either putting "no-cache" in response header or turning off NDB cache does not help. But the same thing happened.

Does anyone know how to turn that cache off? Or there are some codes I need to put in my Python module so that every request would be processed by my module.

Thank you very much!

The code I used is as below. The `print "Start ..."` only execute in the first 2 requests. Starting from 3rd request, `print "Start ..."` is never executed.

```
class ReportServerHandlerJson(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print "Start ..."

        self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
        self.response.headers['Cache-Control']='no-cache,max-age=0'
        self.response.headers['Pragma']='no-cache'
        self.response.headers['Expires']='0'

        # fetch data via Rpt class method
        result=Rpt.GetResult()
        ....
```

**Update**

I think I found some clues. It seems that the response I sent through Python requests module is cached. I am not sure it's cached by Python requests module itself or the GAE.

Still under investigation.

Comment: Are you certain you are not requesting the backend response as a global in your module instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry. I am not pretty sure. I simply follow the document to define a class inherit from webapp2.RequestHandler, define a method "post(self)" and calling REST API inside the method. Would the response become global through this way?

Comment: No, but I've seen several cases where someone didn't realise that the way they stored the data they fetched from elsewhere was subsequently stored as a global, and all they did was re-use that global on each request. You have not shown us the code you used to call the REST service, so we have to make guesses as to possible causes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it. I would paste the code later. Thank you!